# What is the resolution of a scanned pdf file?

Tags: pdf

1. I scanned some documents using a Canon scanner, with resolution
   specified to be 300.

   I saved it into a pdf file Then I checked the resolution of the pdf
   file, by  ImageMagick

   ```
   identify -verbose my.pdf
   ```

   In the output it returns, for every page it says

   ```
   Resolution: 72x72
   ```

   which is not 300 which i specified with the scanner earlier. Why is
   it different? Note: The same problem if I saved it as a jpg file, and if I use a Xerox workCenter.
2. When I use Adobe Premium Pro to OCR my pdf file, it lets me specify
   which resolution that it will downsample the pdf file to from
   several options (72, 300, 600). If I don't want the OCRed pdf file
   to have less resolution than the original pdf file, how shall I find out the resolution of the pdf file, and which resolution
   option shall I choose for OCR in Adobe Premium Pro?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PDF is a vector graphics document. It can be rendered at any resolution.

An raster image embedded in a PDF document (as is typical of a basic scanned document) will typically have a resolution (how many pixels in an inch of the document when printed on paper). One such PDF document may have several of those images (will have if it's a multi-page document) possibly with different resolutions and orientations.

That's not what ImageMagick's `identify -v` reports. That 72dpi is the resolution it uses to convert the PDF into a raster image so as to report pixel information on it.

You'll notice it actually runs: `gs ... -r72x72 ...` for that.

`pdfimages` can report all the raster images in a PDF document:

```
$ pdfimages -list scan.pdf
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID
---------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0 image    1219  1707  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no         8  0
$ qpdf --show-pages --with-images scan.pdf
page 1: 3 0 R
  images:
    /Im0: 8 0 R, 1219 x 1707
  content:
    4 0 R
```

That gives you the size in pixel, but not the size (in `mm` or `inch`) of the box that image would be printed in, so you won't get the resolution from that.

From the object ID (`8 0` above), you can however find out the dimension of the container:

```
$ mutool show scan.pdf grep | grep 'Im0 8 0'
scan.pdf:3: <</Contents 4 0 R/CropBox[0 0 595 842]/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</XObject<</Im0 8 0 R>>/ProcSet 6 0 R>>/Thumb 11 0 R/Type/Page>>
```

So, here, we know the image is rendered on 595x842 pt (a point being 1/72 inch).

So we can derive the x and y resolution:

```
$ echo "$((1219 * 72 / 595))dpi" "$((1707 * 72 / 842))dpi"
147dpi 145dpi
```

Note that when embedded as JPG, the images may have an EXIF header that specifies the resolution.

You can extract the images to find that out:

```
$ exiftool -XResolution -YResolution <(qpdf --show-object=8 --raw-stream-data scan.pdf)
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
```

Here they don't match though.

You can also extract the images and with `pdfimages` and pass that instead to your OCR so that it doesn't have to decide on a resolution before converting itself to a raster image.